# How do you make Windows 10 only use SSD for booting and default to another drive for everything else

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

For years I've done the hack of "Move everything manually" (e.g. move appdata via directory junction, move documents folder, change install drive for software etc.) but it makes resetting my PC extremely tedious, is fragile (many things can break it), and doesn't work for all cases (software can *still* force its files onto my boot drive even if it's installed in another drive).

Is there a way to make it so that if I factory reset windows, I have some simple way of setting it up to move all the large directories to another drive by default, and nuke these directories when I do another reset?

Otherwise, is my only solution to buy a huge SSD and throw all installs and install data in there and just format the drive when I want to nuke everything (or does this get resolved by windows 11)?

Comment: How big is the SSD? How big is the Program Files folder? Usually the advice is to stick everything that needs to load quickly (e.g. Windows) on a SSD, and use a slower but bigger drive for everything else. SSDs are cheap nowadays. Not all programs require fast disk access

Comment: Honestly I'd say don't bother, because eventually you'll want SSD speeds for that "everything else" as well. (Precisely _because_ those installs are large, so they will naturally be slow to load whenever you need anything...), so just get a large SSD from the beginning.

Comment: @Gantendo It's 200gb. The problem isn't how big these get, it's how I can't control where programs put their data. e.g. programs will create its files within the User directory or my Account's directory and I can't prevent that. 

I can resolve these issues that come up, but the thing I want is to have a permant solution that doesn't require me to manually intervene on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Unless installing hundreds of programs, it would be hard to exceed ~250GB an OS partition, provided user data is stored on a different partition, moved via the Location tab in the folder properties of user data directories. While `%AppData%` can be moved, `%LocalAppData%` cannot because it breaks hard links. I've run Windows 8 - 10 on a 300GB partition with >100GB always free even with hundreds of programs installed, so what size SSD is currently being used? Unless prepared to make backing up/restoring a PIA, leave default directories alone and WIM the partition.

Comment: I solved this problem by buying 2 SSDs. One for Windows, one for program files, and sticking everything else on the NAS. 50 euros for 500GB

Comment: @JW0914 "provided user data is stored on a different partition" this is what I want to avoid having to do. It's fragile and has broken on me enough times where I don't want to deal with it anymore. It also doesn't resolve the whole "I want to nuke all of the program's data easily".

Comment: @PickleTickle "_this is what I want to avoid having to do._" It's not being done correctly then, as it's impossible for it to "break" provided it's done correctly via the _Location_ tab found in the _Properties_ of user data directories. Programs are restricted where they can put data, which is almost always `%LocalAppData%`, `%AppData%`, or `%ProgramData%`, as `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, and `%WinDir%` are off-limits _(the first two can only be written to by an installer program, unless a program is run as Admin, and `%WinDir%` is always off-limits)_.

Comment: The only other directory a program may write to is `%Temp%`.

Comment: They can also put it in any one of your C:\Users profiles. Again, I have done this before, and it works, sometimes breaks, and is tedious to fix or setup again. I want a solution that avoids having to manually move things if possible.

To be clear moving:
%ProgramData%
%ProgramFiles%
%ProgramFiles(x86)%
%UserProfile%

Was enough to move all problematic data. I'm just sick of doing it and having it randomly break (last time this happened, I found that Windows remade all those files in the C drive and I had to redirect it all over again).

Comment: @PickleTickle You're making your life way more difficult than it has to be by trying to apply really old methods required in Win7 to do what you wanted to do. The main user data directories within `%UserProfile%` can be moved via each folder's _Properties_' Location tab. Default OS directories are not intended to be moved or symbolically linked and should remain in their default location unless prepared for the PIA that accompanies it - there's simply no use case for moving `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%ProgramData%`, or `%UserProfile%` _(the latter of which contains hard links)_

Comment: @PickleTickle This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/397311). _(it's also not possible for a program running under userX to save in userY's `%UserProfile%` unless ACLs are misconfigured or it's running as Admin, and even then it would require manual interaction since the `%UserProfile%` variable only applies to the currently logged in user - e.g. program would need to save to `C:\Users\userY`, which requires manually doing so)_

Comment: "The main user data directories within %UserProfile% can be moved via each folder's Properties' Location tab" - I have 36 folders in here. 18 of these are `.program_name`. Does this mean I need to go through each file and move it, every time I install a program, and check it periodically to see if there are things that I need to move?

Comment: @PickleTickle The `%UserProfile%` data directories with a _Location_ tab are those contained within the default User Profile [`Contacts`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc.]. Config file directories for programs [`%UserProfile%\.ssh`, `%UserProfile%\.ovpn`, etc.] would still need to be junctioned via `MkLink /J` _(I've always stored user data directories on a partition other than `C:` because it makes for more efficient WIM backups and resotring of the OS partition by separating it from user data and I create junctions for `.ssh`, `.ovpn`, etc. to the user data directory on the non-OS partition)_.

Comment: @PickleTickle _(Cont'd...)_ [This](https://pastebin.com/bnpMfJeA) terminal output shows what I mean _(when the `%UserProfile%` data directories are moved via the folder Properties' Location tab, they show as normal directories, not synlinks)_